# F# Database Type Provider that uses dumb DTOs

Tags: linq-to-sql, f#, type-providers

I've tried searching and can't find any type providers for databases other than the linq one which spits out the connected object types with all the linq information embedded in them.

Was hoping there might be a type provider for SQL databases that spits out a dumb DTO, or if not, a library that will automatically convert them or some such for me so I get the benefits of all the generated types I need, without having to manually created dumb DTOs where I want to have no linq to sql references outside of my repository.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no other database provider currently besides the one based on LINQ. Although some people in the community have been recently trying to convince some other people to write one... What is your main motivation against using the LINQ ones?

Comment: Aside, I believe that the CRM Type Provider (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2013/02/14/the-f-microsoft-dynamics-crm-type-provider-sample-strongly-typed-enterprise-scale-customer-data-made-simple.aspx) implements some of the functionality that would be needed to get a SQL provider...

Comment: @TomasPetricek motivation is just as said in the Q; I the objects spit out from queries/sprocs through linq have all that database specific information bound into them which you're then exposing to other parts of your application if you don't manually create a dumb DTO and manually map the linq's DTO to your dumb one before returning it from your repository. Would be nice if the type provider just spit out a DTO that has nothing in it exposing persistence implementation details like the linq DTOs do.

Comment: If you don't like manually mapping, you could try [automapping](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)...

Comment: @TomasPetricek, correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't there in fact multiple LINQ providers -- one for EDMX files, one for ObjectContexts, one for DBML, etc? And couldn't one use a pure POCO entity model coupled with an EDMX file to do what Jimmy wants?

Comment: @JoelMueller I forgot all about automapper, good thought. Though I would still like the DTOs to be auto-generated like the linq objects are in a type-provider. Might well just go the route of manually making DTOs and auto-mapping them though...

Answer (score 0):

[Fsharp.Data.SqlClient](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/) sounds like what you are looking for. It generates tuples or custom record-like DTOs, and supports Stored Procedures and table-valued UDFs as well. SQL 2012 only though.